# Can PostgreSQL's full-text indexing index 1- or 2-character terms?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

When performing a query like:

```
select count(*) from myTextTable where tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'TERM');
```

I've noticed that PostgreSQL does not use the GIN index (that I defined on the tsv column) when TERM is 1 or 2 characters long; 3 or more characters work fine.

I understand that by indexing 1 or 2 character terms, the size of the index will increase vastly but retrieving texts containing specific 1 or 2 character terms in a fast way is essential for the application I'm developing.

Is there some full text search configuration parameter to index 1- or 2-character terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved now by (a) removing lots of noisy text from the pages (using language detection) and (b) dropping/re-creating the GIN index. My guess is that the noisy text caused an explosion in the number of lexemes and that the index became unusable, or was classified as such by the query planner. –

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I wrote my own to_tsquery() and to_tsvector() methods (in Python), since
I wanted more control. AFAIK the filtering happens in plainto_tsquery(). If you replace this method, you can index single characters, too.

Comment: If I execute `select plainto_tsvector('english', 'tt')` then it returns `['tt':1]`, so it is available in the tsvector. It just does not seem to be indexed by the GIN index (or used by the query optimizer?). I did consider padding the terms with dummy text, but that would mean implementing my own whitespace parsing etc. I'd rather not go there.

Comment: If I do `set enable_seqscan=false;` then a (GIN) index scan **is** performed and the query run time becomes 18 seconds as opposed to 20 minutes! The query plan is way off here.

Comment: Did you a bulk-Insert some minutes ago? The automatic vacuum and analyze needs some time to realize huge updates.

Comment: I did a manual vacuum/analyze/reindex, that didn't help. After setting the 'statistics' value of the tsvector column to 1 the query planner used the index. I'm still investigating what is the matter with the database. It seems that there's a lot of noisy (badly OCR'ed) documents in the database that have caused the index to grow to a huge size; perhaps that is why the query optimizer thinks it's faster to go through the table sequentially vs. using the index.

Comment: What did you exactly mean with `setting the 'statistics' value of the tsvector column to 1`?

Comment: I changed it using the command `ALTER TABLE myTextTable ALTER COLUMN tsv SET STATISTICS 1;`. This changes the query plan in such a way that the index is used instead of a sequential scan.